# URIEncoding not working on Tomcat 6.0.26

Tags: tomcat6, url-encoding

We are working with multiple languages and Korean being one of them, in our application we have set up encoding both at tomcat level and also spring filter for encoding, but for some reason when we do a request.getParameter in our Struts2 action class we receive only ??.

**Tomcat Encoding**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="150"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

**Spring Filter**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

EDIT

So a message which are sent as "안녕하세요 kkk" is received as "????? kkk"

What could I be missing?

Regards,

Ayush

Answer (score 1):

If your labels are in a properties file, try to force utf8 file encoding (check tomcat startup scripts):

1. On Windows
   **set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8**
2. On Linux
   **export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8**

I hope this can help :)

Answer (score 1):

We just had a simliar issue with GET requests being misinterpreted.

The reason was the conflicting use of both `URIEncoding` and `useBodyEncodingForURI` at the same time.

Apparently Tomcat (6) uses a global default (`latin1`?) rather than the encoding defined in `URIEncoding` when processing a GET request (which for obvious reasons has no encoding) if `useBodyEncodingForURI="true"`

Answer (score 0):

How do you send your message? If it's part of the URL then you would have to send an encoded URL like

```
param=%EC%95%88%EB%85%95%ED%95%98%EC%84%B8%EC%9A%94+kkk
```

to get `안녕하세요 kkk` at the server side. See http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ for more information on URL encoding/decoding

If you POST the data in an HTML form to the server than make sure your page is served as UTF-8. You can check this if the response header

```
Content-Type    text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

is present in your page.

Spring's encoding filter should do the trick here. Just make sure, that you declare a filter mapping as well. Otherwise the filter will not be used by the servlet engine:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I know this is odd, but I removed URIEncoding="UTF-8" from my tomcat and the characters seem to be going fine. Cannot understand how this could happen.

Comment: We are sending it as POST.. removing the URIEncoding will cause all GET to not get encoded

Comment: Did you try adding the filter mapping?